# Storyboard - Multiple UITableViewControllers with the same custom cell

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I occasionally find myself `copy/pasting` custom cells between `UITableViews` in my storyboard which is slowly becoming a maintenance nightmare (i.e., a simple change must now be made to each custom cell across several `UITableViews`).

Is it possible to create one custom cell in a storyboard or `xib` file and then reference it from multiple `UITableViews`?  I'm thinking there's got to be a way to specify a `NIB` name for a `static/prototype` cell similar to how you can specify a `NIB` name for a `UIViewController` when editing a normal `xib`.

BTW... I know how to do this via code.  What I'm looking for is a way to do this from within the storyboard editor itself.

Answer (score 1):

I know of a way, but it does require a little code in a custom class. Make a subclass of UITableViewCell that loads itself from a nib. Then just set the class of your cells to this subclass. For a good method of having a view replace itself with a different version loaded from a nib see this [blog post](https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to create a custom class. If you're coding for version 4.0 and up, you can use a UINib to create it. You can also cache it to improve performance.

UIViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINib *cellNib;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyCustomTableViewCell *customCell;
```

UIViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Cache the tableviewcell nib
    self.cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomTableViewCell";

    MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [self.cellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;
        self.customCell = nil;
    }
    // Set title and such
}
```

Don't forget about releasing it in dealloc if not using ARC